# What is similar to ex- pattern to refer to the future

Tags: single-word-requests, prefixes

A normal way to refer to the next president is to call him/her future/next president or president-elect (in case of selecting through an election). However, I'm looking for a pattern to refer to that situation similar to ex- style, e.g. ex-president.

Comment: The only prefix I'm aware of that approaches the right sense even remotely is the extremely polysemous _proto-_ (**proto-** [4] [a]  [forming nouns]:
on the way to becoming the [specified] thing or kind of person) [[Webster’s New World College Dictionary, 4th Edition](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/proto)], but 'proto-president' (2) should mean a 'president in the making' rather than the broader 'future president' and (1) (even more importantly) is not idiomatic.

Comment: You could hyphenate "next-president" or "future-president" if you really must, although it would look a bit odd in many contexts. You don't explain why you need this pattern, so it's kind of hard to see what your problem is or what a valid solution would be.

Answer (score 1):

An idiomatic adjective would be **soon-to-be**.

> The soon-to-be mayor will take office with the city's infrastructure crumbling around him.

But in the spirit of the single-word request, I offer the prefix ***mox-** as an analog to **ex-**.

Comment: I like @Edwin Ashworth’s characterzation above, which applies here too: it “(more importantly) is not idiomatic.”

Comment: Is mox- currently used as a prefix to a reasonable  extent? If not, the answer is invalid on ELU.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: it was offered only as a tongue-in-cheek afterthought to my real idiomatic answer.  I've now annotated it with a leading asterisk, following the convention of grammar books.

Comment: Ballpark answers (the non-prefix) I believe still belong in 'comments'. Non-answers can mislead and unless really funny are best avoided.

Comment: I thought it was really funny.  I don't know what ballpark answers means.  Not following the exact pattern?  OP wasn't all that clear with "similar". Do they want a Latin-derived prefix, so that by "similar" they mean "analogous"?